# Want to convert and SQL to Hibernate Query Language

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a requirement where I have to convert an SQL to HQL.

The SQL query is as follows:

```
select RT.tableNumber, temp.confirmationNumber from ReservationTable RT, (select R.tableNumber, R.confirmationNumber from Reservation R where R.date = 'someDate' and R.time = 'someTime' and R.reservationStatus = 'CONFIRMED') as temp where RT.tableNumber = temp.tableNumber and RT.tableNumber = 'someTableNumber' ;
```

I tried converting it to the following HQL:

```
select RT.tableNumber, temp.confirmationNumber from ReservationTable RT, (select R.tableNumber, R.confirmationNumber from Reservation R where R.date = :param1 and R.time = :param2 and R.reservationStatus = 'CONFIRMED') as temp where RT.tableNumber = temp.tableNumber and RT.tableNumber = :param3";
```

But when I run this HQL through Eclipse, I get the below error lines:

> ERROR: line 1:102: unexpected token: (
>
> ERROR: line 1:146: unexpected token: from
>
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/RRSRestApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 102 [select RT.tableNumber,
>   temp.confirmationNumber from
>   com.kartik.restaurant.model.ReservationTable RT, (select
>   R.tableNumber, R.confirmationNumber from
>   com.kartik.restaurant.model.Reservation R where R.date = :param1 and
>   R.time = :param2 and R.reservationStatus = 'CONFIRMED') as temp where
>   RT.tableNumber = temp.tableNumber and RT.tableNumber = :param3; ]]
>   with root cause org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 102 [select RT.tableNumber,
>   temp.confirmationNumber from
>   com.kartik.restaurant.model.ReservationTable RT, (select
>   R.tableNumber, R.confirmationNumber from
>   com.kartik.restaurant.model.Reservation R where R.date = :param1 and
>   R.time = :param2 and R.reservationStatus = 'CONFIRMED') as temp where
>   RT.tableNumber = temp.tableNumber and RT.tableNumber = :param3; ]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried, but getting the same error. I guess the problem is with the nested query and it being aliased.  Can we actually do something like that in HQL?

Answer (score 0):

According to hibernate documentation HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

[for more detail please follow hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: So how do you think I can convert it to HQL then?